# How to get HtmlElements from a website

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to get urls and html elements from a website.Able to get urls and html from website but, when one url contains multiple elements(like multiple input elements (or)multiple textarea elements)i am able getting only last element.The code like below

GetURLsAndElemens.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException,
                IOException, ParseException {

            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties
                    .load(new FileInputStream(
                            "src//io//servicely//ci//plugin//SeleniumResources.properties"));
            Map<String, String> urls = gettingUrls(properties
                    .getProperty("MAIN_URL"));
            GettingHTMLElements.getHTMLElements(urls);
            // .out.println(urls.size());
            // System.out.println(urls);
        }

        public static Map<String, String> gettingUrls(String mainURL) {
            Document doc = null;
            Map<String, String> urlsList = new HashMap<String, String>();
            try {
                System.out.println("Main URL " + mainURL);

                // need http protocol
                doc = Jsoup.connect(mainURL).get();
                GettingHTMLElements.getInputElements(doc, mainURL);

                // get page title
                // String title = doc.title();
                // System.out.println("title : " + title);

                // get all links
                Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
                for (Element link : links) {
                    // urlsList.clear();

                    // get the value from href attribute and adding to list
                    if (link.attr("href").contains("http")) {
                        urlsList.put(link.attr("href"), link.text());

                    } else {
                        urlsList.put(mainURL + link.attr("href"), link.text());

                    }

                    // System.out.println(urlsList);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // System.out.println("Total urls are "+urlsList.size());
            // System.out.println(urlsList);
            return urlsList;
        }
```

GettingHtmlElements.java

```
static Map<String, HtmlElements> urlList = new HashMap<String, HtmlElements>();

    public static void getHTMLElements(Map<String, String> urls)
            throws IOException {

        getElements(urls);

    }

    public static void getElements(Map<String, String> urls) throws IOException {

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry1 : urls.entrySet()) {

            try {

                System.out.println(entry1.getKey());

                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(entry1.getKey()).get();

                getInputElements(doc, entry1.getKey());

            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        Map<String,HtmlElements> list = urlList;
        for(Map.Entry<String,HtmlElements> entry1:list.entrySet())
        {
            HtmlElements ele = entry1.getValue();
            System.out.println("url is "+entry1.getKey());
            System.out.println("input name "+ele.getInput_name());
        }
    }

    public static HtmlElements getInputElements(Document doc, String entry1) {

        HtmlElements htmlElements = new HtmlElements();
        Elements inputElements2 = doc.getElementsByTag("input");
        Elements textAreaElements2 = doc.getElementsByTag("textarea");
        Elements formElements3 = doc.getElementsByTag("form");

        for (Element inputElement : inputElements2) {
            String key = inputElement.attr("name");
            htmlElements.setInput_name(key);
            String key1 = inputElement.attr("type");
            htmlElements.setInput_type(key1);
            String key2 = inputElement.attr("class");
            htmlElements.setInput_class(key2);

        }
        for (Element inputElement : textAreaElements2) {
            String key = inputElement.attr("id");
            htmlElements.setTextarea_id(key);
            String key1 = inputElement.attr("name");
            htmlElements.setTextarea_name(key1);

                    }
        for (Element inputElement : formElements3) {
            String key = inputElement.attr("method");
            htmlElements.setForm_method(key);
            String key1 = inputElement.attr("action");
            htmlElements.setForm_action(key1);


        }

        return urlList.put(entry1, htmlElements);

    }
```

Which elements i want take it as a bean.For every url i am getting the urls and htmle elements.but when url contains multiple elements i was getting last element only

Answer (score 0):

You use a class `HtmlElements` which is not part of JSoup as far as I know. I don't know its inner workings, but I assume it is some sort of list of html nodes or something.

However, you seem to use this class like this:

```
HtmlElements htmlElements = new HtmlElements();
htmlElements.setInput_name(key);
```

This indicates that only **ONE** html element is stored in the htmlElements variable. This would explain why you get only the last element stored - you simply overwrite the one instance all the time.

It is not really clear, since I don't know the `HtmlElements` class. Maybe something like this works, assuming that `HtmlElement` is working as a single instance of `HtmlElements` and `HtmlElements` has a method `add`:

```
HtmlElements htmlElements = new HtmlElements();
...
for (Element inputElement : inputElements2) {
  HtmlElement e = new HtmlElement();
  htmlElements.add(e);
  String key = inputElement.attr("name");
  e.setInput_name(key);
}
```